# How do I specify ballerina version in ballerina github action?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I am currently using [ballerina-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ballerina-action) GitHub action in my workflow. It seems Ballerina version is hardcoded in the Dockerfile of the GitHub action [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-action/blob/2f23ac5d7810b5b6120a955c84f158c54d08f2fe/Dockerfile#L1). Is there a way to give a specific ballerina version in the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version is hardcoded in the master branch. However, you can use ballerina action with any version you want.

For example,

```yml
- name: Ballerina Action
  uses: ballerina-platform/ballerina-action@2201.3.2
```

Additionally, if you want to do more flexible work with the 'bal' command or work with different versions, you can use the other GitHub action available here: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-ballerina-language